# vb.net conversion

Tags: vb.net

Hi I have the following code snippet for converting files from .xlsm to .xlsx.
The code is in C# but I need it in vb. Pls advice.

```
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\temp\\test.xlsm");
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
 // Change from template type to workbook type
{
spreadsheetDoc.ChangeDocumentType (SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
}
File.WriteAllBytes ("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx", stream.ToArray()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you even tried doing it by yourself? There are few good tools for that kind of conversion available online, like that one: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

```
Dim byteArray As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\temp\test.xlsm")
Using stream As New MemoryStream()
    stream.Write(byteArray, 0, CInt(byteArray.Length))
    Using spreadsheetDoc As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, True)
        ' Change from template type to workbook type
        spreadsheetDoc.ChangeDocumentType(SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)
    End Using
    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\temp\test.xlsx", stream.ToArray())
End Using
```

Comment: +1 the online conversion tools have their limitations (lambdas, AddHandler) but that looks fine.

Comment: yep! tried. got the same converted code. But when I saved a workbook with macros enabled as follows:
spreadsheetDoc.ChangeDocumentType(SpreadsheetDocumentType.MacroEnabled Workbook) and saved, it shows an error like invalid file format on opening the .xlsx file.
Do you have any idea abt it!?